# .8xk decompiler

Tags: math, calculator

I'm in a precalc class and we are allowed to have applications so I decided I would try to make my own. There are a couple of good tutorials but some apps are integrate some cool features not incorporated in these tutorials. So I was wondering if anyone knows of a .8xk decompiler to view the source code of these apps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you like to at least tell us what kind of calculator you are talking about, and maybe link to some apps you want to reverse-engineer?

Comment: sorry I guess that would help but I have the TI-84+ Silver http://education.ti.com/calculators/downloads/US/Software/Search/Results?cp=2 almost all of these are .8xk but they all have nice gui and I get nothing close

Comment: This program will decompile `8XP` files, it's worth a shot for your `8XK`'s: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tibasic/

Comment: @esqew I will try this when I'm on my pc but I don't believe it will work due to these file types being of two separate languages. In spite of that I will try anyway and report back thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Yup, I've written this TI-BASIC and Flash code before, but you must remember it _is_ compiled for a reason.